# How to use hosts entries inside a router?

Tags: networking, router, hosts

I use manual entries inside `/etc/hosts` to map some hosts like `mytestapp.local` to local machine `127.0.0.1` for development purpose.

Now, as I want to access the webapps I work on from mobile devices by their domain, not IP, I think that it would be great if I could move those hosts entries to settings inside the router. The router is ASUS AC87U and the page I think is related to this (but may be I am wrong) looks like this:

[image: admin page]

So, what's the proper place and format to put those entries inside the router so that each client connected to this router searches for this map and uses it?

Answer (score 1):

The router can function as a DNS server, but it may lack functionality for defining response rules. In other words it can simply pass the request to real DNS and passes back the response to the client without any change. I
I have checked the firmware simulation at: http://demoui.asus.com/ and there is no menu for DNS rules definition or DNS cache manipulation. 
The page listed above is for static ip routes. You need static DNS entry.
Best Regards,